# Function does not see field of struct inside struct

Tags: c, struct

So, I have to do library sending IPv4 packets (without libraries with prepared headers) and problem is that I can't access field in struct inside struct while using function, though eclipse does not see error, hint does not show that is possible.

Structs:

```
struct packet{
    struct ipv4hdr * iphdr;
    struct icmphdr * icmphdr;
    char * data;
};
struct ipv4hdr{
    u_int8_t version_length;
    u_int8_t type;
    u_int16_t total_length;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t checksum;
    u_int32_t source;
    u_int32_t destination;
};
```

Pointers to function (that is requirement, both work):

```
struct packet *(*packetCreate)() = dlsym(lib, "createPacket");
void (*setIP)(struct packet *, u_int8_t, u_int8_t, u_int16_t, char*, u_int8_t, char*) = dlsym(lib, "prepareIP");
```

Creation of struct packet:

```
struct packet * createPacket(){
    struct packet * pack= malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
    return pack;
}
```

Now, calling fields inside main does show posssible fields:

```
struct packet * pack = packetCreate();
pack->iphdr->(CTRL+space displays all the fields)   //and eclipse automatically corrects all the . to ->
```

Meanwhile calling created pointer on function does not display fields while using hint and that causes segmentation fault (core dumped):

```
void prepareIP(struct packet * packet, u_int8_t length, u_int8_t type, u_int16_t id, char* destination, u_int8_t ttl, char *data){

    packet->iphdr->type = type;     //it is not treated by error, though any field causes crash
    //meanwhile hint
    packet->iphdr->(CTRL+space gets)ipv4hdr;

}
```

Question again is why I can't call specific field inside function that points to the original struct and how to do this inside that function

Comment: Show us how you allocate space `iphdr` points to.

Comment: Didn't do that, switched the code like 1st answer, packetCreate() was (and still is) all the allocating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to allocate space for `struct ipv4hdr * iphdr;`.

But maybe this isn't even what you intended. Do you really want iphdr to be a pointer in your struct? It makes mucht more sense, if it was *part* of the struct, like this:

```
struct packet{
    struct ipv4hdr iphdr;  // notice that we do not use pointers here!
    struct icmphdr icmphdr; // this looks curious to me - we have either an IP or an ICMP package, why both headers in the same package?
    char * data;
};
```

Comment: Or even `char data[1]`, if it should all be in a single place.

Comment: That fixes that hint problem and now . instad of -> is correct, though still getting core dumped. Shall I malloc these struct inside it?

Comment: Ok, I got error on checksum, you answer fixed the problem. 
BTW. your attention about icmp is not correct, ICMP is inside IPv4 frame, and it has it's own header. It may have been included inside, but it is something totally diffrent

Comment: @Myszsoda yes, maybe I was not clear enough about my thoughts. I was just wondering that ICMP is mandatory in your implementation, while it is optional in the standard. You must specify the protocol in your `iphdr.protocol`field, which is now forced to be 1 (for ICMP) in your implementation. Maybe you want to consider ICMP to be an optional feature in your implementation to have more flexibility.

Comment: @Ctx nice idea, but two things to take care of: 1. the size of your payload must be known while malloc'ing the struct and 2. if the proper C extensions are available on all plattforms you want to support, you can use char data[0] (however, I do not recommend this, because it is an extension)

Comment: @UniversE I didn't paste the whole code, just a problem. Indeed, my task is to do IPv4 ICMP, and so I did, but for the sake of essence of the problem I pasted sample to fix whole code. Program includes all of the features you have written about.